# Servlet 404 the requested resource [/ServletDemo/AddServlet] is not available

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-404

I just started learning about Servlets. I followed the basic steps to create a new servlet project:

> File -> new -> Dynamic Web Project -> new -> Servlet (AddServlet) with a basic print statement in the doGet()

```
package com.demo.servlets;
//all of my imports

@WebServlet("/AddServlet")
public class AddServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public AddServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().print("Hello");
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

I'll I've done is make the servlet but I can't get past this step. I've looked at a million tutorials and stack overflow answers. I made sure Tomcat 9.0 was installed and connected to my project correctly, made sure the servlet version was 4.0, made sure my build path was correct, made sure that my servlet was in a package.

[image]

I've also even tried using web.xml instead of the web annotations but I get the same  404error. . Ive been working on this for the past 72 hours, and I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Could you add `@Override` annotation above the `doGet` and `doPost`?

Comment: @MustafaÇil wow i can't believe my eyes, that just solved it. Is the override something that is needed? I hadn't seen it mentioned in any tutorials.

Comment: I am happy for that, I will write solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `doGet` and `doPost` from `HttpServlet`. For this reason you need to add `@Override` annotation above the `doGet` and `doPost`.